# SharedPreferences not showing text

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Storing String in a SharedPreferences, and then showing in EditText but when i do re-launch my app, getting EditText blank...

```
strCompanyName = jsonObject.getString("company_name");

SharedPreferences sharedPrefdd= getSharedPreferences("myprefss", 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPrefdd.edit();

editor.putString("name", strCompanyName);
editor.commit();

editCompanyName.setText(sharedPrefdd.getString("name", ""));
```

Comment: Move your code on `onResume()` method.

Comment: Are you sure strCompanyName  is not empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your code to `onResume()` method.

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    editCompanyName.setText(preferii.getString("name", "")); 
}
```